# Hide tooltip when mouse over option tag

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I'm using bootstrap and [multiselect plugin](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/).

In js I'm creating a dropdown with options with particular value.

```
if( $('#function_nodes option:contains("'+root.nodes[k].title.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g,'\\$1')+'")').length == 0 )
funNodes.append("<option value='" + root.nodes[k].name + "'>" + nodeLabel + "</option>");
```

However when I hover over the option, the value, which is node name in my case, is displayed in the tooltip somehow, how should I disable tooltip in this case?
[image: On hover toolip is]

Comment: Could you explain more? jsfiddle?!

Comment: @negative0 added screenshot

Comment: Add in css for this element where you added tooltip  - position: relative

Comment: Please add more details for us with which we can easily recreate your issue so we can help you efficiently. (ex. a JSFiddle)